# Downloading Images with FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebaseui

I was trying to add to my project firebase-ui-storage

```
The latest version is: firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1
```

But when adding it with these:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
```

It complains that the storage is 11.0.1 and when I am trying to run the code I am getting multiple dex files...
Is there a new version of firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1

I wanted to implement this

```
First, add FirebaseUI to your app/build.gradle:

dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
Then you can load images directly from Storage into an ImageView:

// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

Comment: can you share the logact

Answer (score 0):

Please try after altering version number.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.1'
```

Check this [link](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).